# How to integrate Paypal Subscription for Merchants? (Third Party - Is there a way ?)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm searching for 2 days to integrate the Paypal Subscription method into my service. I integrated payment services to my merchants easily but I couldn't find any clear information for the subscription model.

Do you know "How Can I integrate PayPal subscription to my service for merchants ?"

to integrate that model;

-> Create a Paypal Product 
-> Create a Paypal Plan 
-> Create a subscription with Product  and Plan

So, I need to create a product and plan also in my merchant's accounts.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You will need each merchant's clientid and secret from a REST app in  [developer.paypal.com](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) (use that link with sign-in) , to do the necessary API calls to create a product and a plan.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much for your help. I will optimize my service as your suggestion.